# Calling lambda recursively in sam local invoke

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

How can I recursively call lambda inside itself in sam local environment?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.foo = async(event, context) => {
  // .......
  lambda.invoke({ FuncitonName: context.functionName, InvocationType: 'Event', Payload: {/* .... */}})
}
```

This apparently does not work.

EDIT

My usecase is to split data to prevent timeout.
`Payload` contains page number and this lambda fetches data from API with the page number and put it to DynamoDB.
Returning result to caller is not important so async invocation is fine.

Comment: What is the point to call a lambda function recursively ? Could you describe your use case ?
What is the output of your execution ?

Comment: Wouldn't doing this create an endless loop?

Comment: Actually, `lambda.invoke` is under guard condition. I omitted that for brevity

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call other function I would recommend using `localstack` which has better support working with lambda functions locally and inter-calls between them.

`sam local` is fine if you work only with the function itself but once you have integration with s3, dynamodb, sqs, lambda better to use `localstack`